# C++ for loop strange behaviour

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I believe that two loops below are identical, anybody know why they work different in case |s1| > |s2|?

```
string s1 = "abcd";
string s2 = "abc";

int s1len = s1.length()
int s2len = s2.length()

for (int i = 0; i <= s2len - s1len; i++) {
    // it will never calls (as expected, since 3 - 4 = -1)
}

for (int i = 0; i <= s2.length() - s1.length(); i++) {
    // it calls once (which is strange)
}
```

Comment: You forgot (a) the `;` on both of your length assignments, and (b) [the **warnings** your compiler should be giving you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/022bba8b76446e64) for a possible problems. If you don't see those warnings, time to crank up your warning level.

Comment: Did it from memory without testing, but it's helpful to know, thanx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::string::length()` returns an unsigned integer type. Unsigned intergal types follow modular arithmetic, such that -1 maps to the larges value of that type. This means the subtraction in your second loop yields a very large number instead of a negative one.

You could have tried this to figure it out by yourself:

```
std::cout << s2.length() - s1.length() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you! Is `for (int i = 0; i <= (int)s2.length() - (int)s1.length(); i++) {` best way to calculate it right without additional variables?

Comment: @user3537411 "best way" is a relative term, because an `int` does not usually cover the range of `std::string::size_type`, which is usually `std::size_t`.  A string's length could be a value so large it does not fit into an `int`. So it really depends on what you want to do. One option would be to calculate the absolute difference, and then branch depending on which of the lengths is larger.